# How to open a react native modal on button click in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, onclick, modal-dialog

I am new to react native and I am trying to open a modal on button click.
I am trying to use the following code to open the modal:-

```
  openHeaderModal = () => {
    <ModalDropdown
      options={["H1", "H2", "H3"]}
      dropdownStyle={{
        borderRadius: 6,
        backgroundColor: "#26344a",
        shadowColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)",
        shadowOffset: {
          width: 0,
          height: 5
        },
        shadowRadius: 20,
        shadowOpacity: 1,
        padding: 8
      }}
      dropdownTextStyle={{
        fontFamily: "poppins-500",
        fontSize: 16,
        fontStyle: "normal",
        letterSpacing: 0,
        textAlign: "left",
        color: "#ffffff",
        backgroundColor: "#26344a"
      }}
    >
    </ModalDropdown>
  }
```

I am using react-native-modal-dropdown for modal.
Following is my jsx code for the buton:-

```
  <Button onPress={() => this.openHeaderModal()} vertical>
     <Image
       style={{ marginTop: 20 }}
       source={require("../assets/heading.png")}
     />
  </Button>
```

Any help and support is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: So what is your problem? Are you getting exception? Or no exception but system hang...?Or.........?

Comment: The problem is it doesn't open the modal. But when I place the button within the modal tags it works.I want to open it on click of the button.

Comment: Try to setup the environment @ https://snack.expo.io/

Comment: The official GitHub did shared all the codes needed to use this module, have you checked them out? https://github.com/sohobloo/react-native-modal-dropdown/blob/master/example/index.js

Comment: Thanks @Isaac I'll go through this also this is the link to my code on snack https://snack.expo.io/SkeuBuw-m

Comment: The snack you created can't allow us to help as it includes too many missing png files. Please remove whatever unnecessary for your question and at least run the simulator one time to make sure able to simulate your problem

Comment: Ok will do that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173444/discussion-between-androidnewbee-and-isaac).

Answer (score 2):

I think open a Modal in react-native very easy, simple example:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Modal, Text, TouchableHighlight, View} from 'react-native';

class ModalExample extends Component {
  state = {
    modalVisible: false,
  };

  setModalVisible(visible) {
    this.setState({modalVisible: visible});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{marginTop: 22}}>
        <Modal
          animationType="slide"
          transparent={false}
          visible={this.state.modalVisible}
          onRequestClose={() => {
            alert('Modal has been closed.');
          }}>
          <View style={{marginTop: 22}}>
            <View>
              <Text>Hello World!</Text>

              <TouchableHighlight
                onPress={() => {
                  this.setModalVisible(!this.state.modalVisible);
                }}>
                <Text>Hide Modal</Text>
              </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
          </View>
        </Modal>

        <TouchableHighlight
          onPress={() => {
            this.setModalVisible(true);
          }}>
          <Text>Show Modal</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Link: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal.html#docsNav

If you want to use library: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-modal

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the example given by @Issac at https://github.com/sohobloo/react-native-modal-dropdown/blob/master/example/index.js and solved the problem.
Following is the code to inflate the Modal drop down on a button click:-

```
 <ModalDropdown
              style={{ marginLeft: 50 }}
              ref={el => this._dropdown_5 = el}
              defaultValue=''
              dropdownStyle={{
                borderRadius: 6,
                backgroundColor: "#26344a",
                shadowColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)",
                shadowOffset: {
                  width: 0,
                  height: 5
                },
                shadowRadius: 20,
                shadowOpacity: 1,
                padding: 8
              }}
              dropdownTextStyle={{
                fontFamily: "poppins-500",
                fontSize: 16,
                fontStyle: "normal",
                letterSpacing: 0,
                textAlign: "left",
                color: "#ffffff",
                backgroundColor: "#26344a"
              }}
              options={['H1', `H2`, 'H3']}
              onDropdownWillShow={this._dropdown_5_willShow.bind(this)}

            />
```

code for the onPress of the button:-

```
<Button onPress={this._dropdown_5_show.bind(this)} vertical >
                  <Image style={{ marginTop: 20 }} style={{}} source={require("../assets/heading.png")} />
                </Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find below link for modal demo
https://reactnativecode.com/react-native-modal-ios-android/